# Arduino Mega (Atmega 1280) avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00

Tags: arduino

I have just received my arduino mega 1280 and I am trying to load my firmware within it, but I am getting once and again the same error :

avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00

I have checked the other posts presents in SO about this issue and I am already sure about these points:

- I am using the correct COM port
- I am selecting the correct board

Moreover I have uninstalled and installed the arduino drivers ( I have windows 8 and I have disabled the digital firm stuff) , I can see in the device manager the virtual com port despite its name is not "arduino something" but simply "USB serial port" ,is it a bad signal?

Are there other options I must consider before to blame the bootloader?

Thank you very much!!!

Cristina

Answer (score 1):

Well, the MEGA 1280 has a FT232, so you should definitely see a "USB serial port".

As for the error, i usually get it when i use custom-made boards without the automatic reset feature. Try to press the reset button when the IDE says "started downloading the firmware" (or something similar). Just press and release it, as if you want to reset the arduino.

If it doesn't work, see if the RX, TX and L led blink during the downloading. If RX and TX are shut down there is some problem with the serial communication, if the L led is off the problem could be with the bootloader.

If nothing works.. Try flashing the bootloader again..

Comment: Thanks! It was absolutely a problem with the bootloader, I fixed it flashing it again

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error on Mac. I solved it doing the following:

Select in the Tools menu:

```
  * Board: Arduino Mega or Mega 2560
  * Port: cu.usbmodemXXXX or tty.usbmodemXXXX
  * Processor:ATmega2560 (Yes, not ATmega1280)
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work for me :-/ , It was a bootloader problem. I flashed it again and problem solved